# Extract nested object structure from flat list

Tags: c#, linq, tree

I've got a list of objects that look like this:

```
public class AllTablesView
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContractDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string CarColor { get; set; }
    public string CarPlateNumber { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceValue { get; set; }
}
```

The actual class is bigger than this, having properties of at least 12 different entities, and they should look like this when converted:

```
public class Client
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContractDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Car 
{
    public string CarColor { get; set; }
    public string CarPlateNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceValue { get; set; }
}
```

Like I said, this goes on a little bit, but the structure is the same. I'd like to know how I could extract the nested objects structure from the "AllTablesView" class.

I've attempted to use Linq's Group By but then I had to group by every entity and then loop through, it wasn't practical considering the amount of entities.

One note is that I have some logic when creating some of the objects, as an example: the invoice type is defined based on the client id.

EDIT:
One thing I've forgot and will probably impact the answer. The data that fills these properties come from the database, and is not grouped. Which means that the client id will repeat multiple times, but it is essentially the same client, so I cannot create it again. This is true for every entity I've exposed here, probably not so much for the invoice.

The goal is to create a json file which has this "tree" represented, without duplication.

Comment: Why don't you convert your initial list of AllTablesView to XML and then serialize this to json?

Comment: order class defenition is missing

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach to represent nested object structure is to use XML. So, for example, you could easily build up an XML string representing clients and their corresponding contracts like this:

```
XElement xeBody =
    new XElement("Clients",

       // for each client in the list of all tables
       from client in lstAllTables
       //...group by client id into client group
       group client by client.ClientId into clientGroup
        //... for each client int the group create a <Client> element 
        select new XElement("Client",
           new XAttribute("ClientId", clientGroup.First().ClientId),
           new XAttribute("ClientName", clientGroup.First().ClientName),

           // for each contract in the current client group create a <Contract> element
           from contract in clientGroup
           select new XElement("Contract",
              new XAttribute("ContractNumber", contract.ContractNumber),
              new XAttribute("ContractDate", contract.ContractDate)
           )
       )
   );
```

With this as input:

```
List<AllTablesView> lstAllTables = new List<AllTablesView>()
{                
    new AllTablesView() { ClientId = "1", ClientName = "Bob", ContractNumber = "BC1001", ContractDate = "2014-12-07" },
    new AllTablesView() { ClientId = "1", ClientName = "Bob", ContractNumber = "BC1002", ContractDate = "2014-12-08" },
    new AllTablesView() { ClientId = "1", ClientName = "Bob", ContractNumber = "BC1003", ContractDate = "2014-12-08" },
    new AllTablesView() { ClientId = "2", ClientName = "Jim", ContractNumber = "AD1003", ContractDate = "2014-12-08" },
    new AllTablesView() { ClientId = "2", ClientName = "Jim", ContractNumber = "AD1004", ContractDate = "2014-12-08" }
};
```

you get the following XML:

```
<Clients>
  <Client ClientId="1" ClientName="Bob">
    <Contract ContractNumber="BC1001" ContractDate="2014-12-07" />
    <Contract ContractNumber="BC1002" ContractDate="2014-12-08" />
    <Contract ContractNumber="BC1003" ContractDate="2014-12-08" />
  </Client>
  <Client ClientId="2" ClientName="Jim">
    <Contract ContractNumber="AD1003" ContractDate="2014-12-08" />
    <Contract ContractNumber="AD1004" ContractDate="2014-12-08" />
  </Client>
</Clients>
```

You can fiddle with the XML generation code above to produce the desired xml structure, including the rest of the classes referred to in the OP and effectively avoiding any data duplication.

You could finally use [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to serialize XML to Json.

Comment: I had some trouble to generate the end XML considering I had to group by each and every entity, but this definetelly helped me get there. I appreciate it.

Comment: One thing I'm still a bit confused about is the reason behind calling "First" on the grouping. I was doing something similar but using the "group.Key" property and it didnt work just as good as your solution. Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: @BrenoSarkis Grouping in Linq does not work the way grouping works in SQL. This is a very good article to understand grouping in Linq: http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/08/how-to-use-grouping-in-c-linq-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to automatically extract a class from another class. You might try adding extension methods instead that extract the information you need, for example:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Client GetClient(this AllTablesView view)
    {
        return new Client()
                   {
                       ClientID = view.ClientID,
                       ClientName = view.ClientName,
                   };
    }
}
```

Then getting your classes out looks a little simpler:

```
Client client = myAllTableView.GetClient();
```

Likely not the answer you were hoping for, but beyond some code auto-generation tool, I don't see LINQ necessarily helping out here.

**Edit**: For grouping manually, you could try something like the following to check if it already exists:

```
Dictionary<int, Client> clients = new Dictionary<int, Client>();

foreach (AllTableView tableView in AllTableViewCollection)
{
    if (clients.ContainsKey(tableView.ClientID) == false)
    {
        clients.Add(tableView.GetClient());
    }
}
```

This is, of course, doing it yourself. Someone else may have a better idea for a way to automate this through LINQ.

Comment: I've updated my question, this is how I've done it the first time, but then I realized I needed to group the results, which broke this. Can you give it a try now? Sorry though.

Comment: @BrenoSarkis I added how to do the grouping yourself, although someone else may know a way to do it through LINQ. With the complexity needed with checking each of the multiple classes, it might be better than a LINQ equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Will, I ended up using Giorgios solution. but I voted you up, since it helped my thought process